# Call service method from ng-bind and other directives

Tags: angularjs

I've a many functions which is repeated in many controllers and for now I just copy and paste it there but what I want is to create 1 global function and inject and call it in all controller.

for example :

```
<div ng-bind="mycustomreturn(scopeVal)"></div>
```

which is the best way to do it in service or in root scope I dont want my root scope to be very large so please suggest if we can do it by service

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to share data in angular is by using Services:

```
angular.module('test', []).service('MyService', function() {

  this.mycustomreturn = function() {}

})
.controller(function(MyService) {

  // you have two ways

  //One:
  $scope.MyService = MyService;
  // and the view will be:
  //<p>{{MyService.mycustomreturn()}}</p>

  //Two:
  $scope.mycustomreturn = MyService.mycustomreturn();
  // and the view will be:
  //<p>{{mycustomreturn}}</p>

});
```

Comment: but in every controller I've to initialize all custom function like that ?

Comment: Yes, inject where you need, this is a bad practice to put things on the rootScope.